# Is the lenth of the normal vector of two known vectors a changeless constant?

Tags: python, vector

As known,the normal vector can be calculated with cross product. My question is that I got diffrent normal vector lenths of the same pair of vectors in different coordinate systems.Here is the code, `Vs12`/`Vs13` are the known vectors.

```
def crossProduct(Vs12,Vs13):
    Fs1=Vs12[1]*Vs13[2]-Vs13[1]*Vs12[2]
    Fs2=-Vs12[0]*Vs13[2]+Vs13[0]*Vs12[2]
    Fs3=Vs12[0]*Vs13[1]-Vs13[0]*Vs12[1]
    Fs=np.array([Fs1,Fs2,Fs3])
    return Fs
def vectorLenth(x,y,z):
    lenth_V=(x**2+y**2+z**2)**1/2
    return lenth_V

lenth_Fs=vectorLenth(Fs[0],Fs[1],Fs[2])
lenth_Ft=vectorLenth(Ft[0],Ft[1],Ft[2])

lenth_Fs
 3460825052841.606 
lenth_Ft
3460925056778.934
```

`Fs`/`Ft` is the normal vector in different coordinate systems. Is the value in the allowed error range？

the lenths of the three points in coordinate system 1 are

```
3277117.1973625002，15955141.603046002，5011646.0980985
```

in coordinate system 2 they are

```
3277163.597499995 ，15955363.79005001 ，5011715.192850016
```

They are close to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation seems correct. However, as the magnitude of the cross-product of two vectors `a` and `b` is given by `||a x b|| = ||a||*||b||*sin(theta)` where `theta` is the angle between `a` and `b`, the length of the cross product is independent of the chosen coordinate system. What coordinate systems do you use? Without given vectors `Vs12` and `Vs13` in both coordinate systems it is not possible to tell what went wrong.

Comment: **Thanks! The three points in coordinate system 1 are**
`Ps1=np.array([352.45,5643.87,89.43])
Ps2=np.array([265.435,3085.45,123.34])
Ps3=np.array([1189.324,57.324,110.14])`

**in coordinate 2 are**
`Pt1=np.array([48638.78,39746.41,6028.4])
Pt2=np.array([50795.75,40894.7,5264.7])
Pt3=np.array([53155.29,42994.41,5047.4])`

Comment: `lenth_Fs
 3460825052841.606 
lenth_Ft
3460925056778.934`
The error comes after the fifth digit position.It is only an acceptable error,maybe?

Comment: I do not understand what these three vectors are. You did not mention them in your question.

Comment: **Sorry.**I mean Ps1,Ps2,Ps3 are 3D points in coordinate system1.Vetor `Vs12=Ps2-Ps1,Vs13=Ps3-Ps1`.Fs is the normal vector.Pt1,Pt2,Pt3 are 3D points in coordinate system2.Ft is the normal vector in coordinate system 2 calculated in the same way.Sorry for the unclear statment.